# Mod operation while verifying an ECDSA signature with SECT233R1

Tags: hash, elliptic-curves, signature, sha-256, dsa

I'm trying to perform ECDSA verification in hardware. I'm using the SECT233R1 curve (NIST B-233). I have a question about the hash function used while doing so.

I want to use the SHA256 hash function while signing and verifying. In this case, the hash function will have a larger message length (256-bits) than the elliptic curve finite field element (233-bits).

I have the same question as [this](https://groups.google.com/g/mailing.openssl.users/c/yMAJVCU9TLI/m/Ry13hBLskc0J). Is it sufficient to operate on the lower 233-bits?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it sufficient to operate on the lower 233-bits (of the SHA-256 hash)?

**No**. That's not my reading of the de-facto reference: [sec1v2's statement of ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.4.1.3), section 5 (with the second case of section 5.2 applicable), combined with the endianness specification of [SHA-256](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf#page=12).

When signing per ECDSA with curve [sect233r1](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#subsubsection.3.3.2) and SHA-256, one should keep the leftmost/first/high-order 233 bits of the SHA-256 hash, and consider this as an integer per big-endian convention.

That is keep the first 29 out of 32 bytes, and the high-order bit of the 30<sup>th</sup> byte. That later bit will be the parity of the integer $e$ used in next steps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!